# MaterialUI / ReactJS: MobileDatePicker not closing after date select

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using closeOnSelect on this, but after selecting a date it remains open - only escaping or clicking OK or Cancel buttons does it disappear. I am using this on both desktop and mobile.

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
<MobileDatePicker
style={{ width: '100%' }}
label={"Date From"}
inputFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
closeOnSelect={true}
views={['day']}
value={abc}
renderInput={(params) => <TextFields {...params} fullWidth />}
/>
</LocalizationProvider>
```

How do I make sure this closes after selecting date?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set `disableCloseOnSelect` prop to false.

```
<LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
   <MobileDatePicker
      style={{ width: '100%' }}
      label={"Date From"}
      inputFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
      disableCloseOnSelect={false}
      views={['day']}
      value={abc}
      renderInput={(params) => <TextFields {...params} fullWidth />}
   />
</LocalizationProvider>
```

Check codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/date-picker-material-ui-forked-so0v14

Comment: Sorry @cdoshi ... this still remains open after selecting a date

Comment: I have added a codesandbox. Give it a spin.

Answer (score 0):

I made a slight change in your code. I hope it can help you:

- you have to add required props for your date picker, e.g. {onChange, value }
- datePickers won't accept style as props here

```
import * as React from "react";
import TextField from "@mui/material/TextField";
import { AdapterDateFns } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/AdapterDateFns";
import { LocalizationProvider } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/LocalizationProvider";

import { MobileDatePicker } from "@mui/x-date-pickers/MobileDatePicker";


export default function MaterialUIPickers() {
  const [value, setValue] = React.useState<Date | null>(
    new Date("2014-08-18T21:11:54")
  );

  const handleChange = (newValue: Date | null) => {
    setValue(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <LocalizationProvider dateAdapter={AdapterDateFns}>
      <MobileDatePicker
        label={"Date From"}
        inputFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"
        value={value}
        views={["day"]}
        onChange={handleChange}
        renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} fullWidth />}
      />
    </LocalizationProvider>
  );
}
```

Comment: mirazei - i fail to see how this closes the date picker on selecting a date? I have a value and an onchange already - I omitted the onchange as I don't believe it is relevant as it is just a setValue

Comment: the code you provided doesn't have any onChange and appropriate value, If you changed your code, please update